# How does Cross-validation prevent the Recursive Partitioning for Heterogeneous Causal Effects from over fitting?

Tags: cross-validation

I have a question regarding the steps in the Casual Tree algorithm based on Dr. Athey's paper, entitled " Recursive partitioning for heterogeneous causal effects".

Does the algorithm use cross-validation to avoid overfitting in step 2 and step 4? or only in step 2?

Step 1: Randomly splitting the original dataset into two subsets with equal size: S1, S2

Step 2: S1 will be split into subgroups to find the highest treatment effect by comparing treatment vs. control group ( Note: The cross-validation is applied)

Step3: The cut point values from step 2 will be re-estimated based on S2

Step 4: Repeat step 1 to step 3 for cross-validation purpose